# Computing PDF two random variables

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be uniform on $[1, 2]$ and $Y$ be independent exponential with parameter $\lambda = 1$.  Define $Z = Y/X$ and compute its PDF.

My approach has been to first find its CDF as follows, $F_{Z}(z) = P(Z \leq z) = P(Y/X \leq z) = \int\int_{\{(x, y) : y/x \leq z\}}f_{X, Y}(x, y)dx dy = \int\int_{\{(x, y) :y/x \leq z\}}f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)dxdy$.
But now I'm having difficulties with the bounds of integration.  I'm inclined to take it from $1 \leq x \leq 2$ and $1 \leq Y \leq 2$ as outside this interval the PDF of $X$ is zero so the integrand $f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)$ is non-zero on that interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fixed $z$, we want to find $\Pr(Y\le zX)$. If $z\le 0$, the probability is $0$. So from now on assume that $z\gt 0$.

Draw the line $y=zx$. Let $D$ be the region which is below the line, above the $x$-axis, from $x=1$ to $x=2$. Then
$$\Pr(Y\le zX)=\iint_D e^{-y}\,dx\,dy.$$
To find the answer, integrate first with respect to $y$, from $y=0$ to $y=zx$, then with respect to $x$, from $1$ to $2$.

It is marginally easier to find first $\Pr(Y\gt zX$. To do this, let $E$ be the region above the line $y=zx$, between $x=1$ and $x=2$. We need the double integral over $E$ of the joint density. So
$$\Pr(Y\gt zX)=\int_1^2 \left(\int_{zx}^\infty e^{-y} \,dy\right)\,dx.$$

Comment: Thank you that helps a lot.

Comment: You are welcome. To solve the problem, I immediately drew a picture.